# Match multiple CSS classes

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

Is there a select expression for matching tags with multiple classes?

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="foo bar"></div>
</div>
```

I could match it with `soup.select('div#top div.foo')` or `soup.select('div#top div.bar')`.

But I need both classes to be there.

Is there an expression for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain class selectors. `.foo.bar` means only select elements with both class `foo` and class `bar`

```
soup.select('div#top div.foo.bar')
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the [CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html), the following rule matches any `div` element whose `class` attribute has been assigned a list of space-separated values that includes `foo` and `bar`:

```
div.foo.bar
```

BeautifulSoup also follows this spec, so you can use:

```
soup.select('div#top div.foo.bar')
```

Comment: By the way...this is [right in the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)